# Converting Number to Integer

Tags: c, int, type-conversion

I need to get a number potentially outside the signed integer range from a string into an integer. I always get the number 0 if the value is outside the signed integer limit. I understand that 0 means the conversion failed.

Here is what I've tried:

Now the data will always be under the int limit so storing it into an int shouldn't be a problem. Even when changing the type to a long I still get 0.

```
int getData(char* data){
    char *end;
    unsigned int x = strtol (data, &end, 7);
    return x;
}
```

I have tried putting the value into an unsigned int and returning to an unsigned int. It doesn't matter I don't even get the right conversion out of it.

```
int getData(char* data){
    unsigned x = atoi(data);
    return x;
}
```

I have also tried this that I found on another stack exchange thread. No luck here either.

```
int getData(char* data){
    int x = strtoul(data, NULL, 10);
    return x;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you want the result to be `base 7` with `strtoul(data, NULL, 7)`, i think it should be `strtoul(data, NULL, 10)`

Comment: Good catch, but it doesn't matter if I replace it with a 10.

Comment: Let us know what you got from this code and what you were expecting

Comment: You have to set `strtoul` base to base 10 if you want to convert a string to integer. Do you want base 7 with this `strtol (data, &end, 7);` you need to read the man page [strtoul(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Comment: I am expecting to get a number other than 0. It doesn't matter what base I choose. I always get 0. For example if data contains 3147483647 I want to see that number in an unsigned int called x.

Comment: And you said this code `int getData(char* data){ int x = strtoul(data, NULL,10); return x;}` is giving you 0 all the time. I am not getting 0 when i pass "3147483647" in as data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that 0 means the conversion failed.

Not quite.

If `strto*()` is returning 0, then either

1. Conversion was successful and the string was something like `"0"`, `"  0"`
2. Conversion failed. string was something like `""`, `"--123"` or `"abc"`.

To distinguish, test the `endptr`.  A more robust `getData()` with error messages  follows:

```
int getData(const char* data){
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0; 
    long x = strtol (data, &end, 10);

    // This is the missing code needed for OP to locate the issue
    if (data == end) {
      printf("No conversion <%s>\n", data);

    } else if (errno) {
      printf("Overflow/implementation defined error, %d, <%s>\n", errno == ERANGE, data);
    }
    if (x < INT_MIN || x > INT_MAX) {
      printf("Overflow (long to int), %ld <%s>\n", x, data);
      x = x < 0 ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX; 
      errno = ERANGE;
    }
    return (int) x;
}
```

I suspect OP's code is 1) not calling `getData()` with the expected *string* or 2) OP's code is not printing the returned value properly.

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is a bit odd, it should work, nevertheless. But `strtol` returns a `long`, so there is a bit more work needed to get an `unsigned int` properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

// using "long" for a bit more clarity, adapt according to your needs
long getData(char *data)
{
  char *end;
  // reset errno before use.
  errno = 0;
  // variable "end" unused here
  long x = strtol(data, &end, 10);
  // from the manpage
  if ((errno == ERANGE && (x == LONG_MAX || x == LONG_MIN))
      || (errno != 0 && x == 0)) {
    // set errrno for caller (not the best idea here, 
    // this function should return its own error variable)
    errno = ERANGE;
    return LONG_MIN;
  }
  return x;
}
// example to get an unsigned int
unsigned int getUData(char *data)
{
  char *end;
  // reset errno before use.
  errno = 0;
  // use strtoul() instead
  unsigned long x = strtoul(data, &end, 10);
  // from the manpage
  if ((errno == ERANGE && (x == ULONG_MAX))
      || (errno != 0 && x == 0)) {
    // set errrno for caller (not the best idea here, 
    // this function should return its own error variable)
    errno = ERANGE;
    return UINT_MAX;
  }
  // check if it fits into an unsigned int
  if(x > UINT_MAX ){
    // should return a different error, of course
    errno = EDOM;
    return UINT_MAX;
  }

  return (unsigned int)x;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  long ret;
  unsigned int uret;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s integer\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // reset errno
  errno = 0;
  // get the input transformed
  ret = getData(argv[1]);
  // check for errors
  if (ret == LONG_MIN && errno != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while trying to transform %s to a long\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else {
    printf("getData(%s) returned %ld\n", argv[1], ret);
  }

  // reset errno
  errno = 0;
  // get the input transformed
  uret = getUData(argv[1]);
  // check for errors
  if (uret == UINT_MAX && errno != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while trying to transform %s to an unsigned int\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else {
    printf("getUData(%s) returned %u\n", argv[1], uret);
  }

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I put all checks into one `if`; you might find it a better idea to put them apart to get a bit more information out of it to find your error.